# binding multiple textures based on verticies

Tags: javascript, textures, webgl

My problem is that I am trying to set a certain texture onto triangles via retrieving verticies from a text file. Basically I want to be able to go through each matrix and set a value for the texture I want it to set. Right now I have it set to only 1 texture for literally everything. I am taking this from an example, but this is straight webgl no libraries or anything I am strictly using this for de-engineering and learning purposes. There must be a way to do this for I am doing this for the x,y,z coordinates and texture coordinates.

```
    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, rockTexture);
    gl.uniform1i(shaderProgram.samplerUniform, 0);
```

I've looked up some documentation, and you can't bind an array to a texture like you can for bindBuffer, basically I am just trying to grab a value from a text file to determine which texture I want it to be. Some help, or even a step in the right direction with some explanation would do wonders.

Example of how I am doing this with coordinates:

(text file example)

```
// Floor 1
-25.0  0.0 -25.0 0.0 25.0
-25.0  0.0  25.0 0.0 0.0
 25.0  0.0  25.0 25.0 0.0

-25.0  0.0 -25.0 0.0 25.0
 25.0  0.0 -25.0 25.0 25.0
 25.0  0.0  25.0 25.0 0.0

// Ceiling 1
-25.0  4.0 -25.0 0.0 24.0
-25.0  4.0  25.0 0.0 0.0
 25.0  4.0  25.0 24.0 0.0
-25.0  4.0 -25.0 0.0 24.0
 25.0  4.0 -25.0 24.0 24.0
 25.0  4.0  25.0 24.0 0.0
```

And then it parses and connects it through here:

```
var lines = data.split("\n");
        var vertexCount = 0;
        var vertexPositions = [];
        var vertexTextureCoords = [];
        for (var i in lines) {
            var vals = lines[i].replace(/^\s+/, "").split(/\s+/);
            if (vals.length == 6 && vals[0] != "//") {
                // It is a line describing a vertex; get X, Y and Z first
                vertexPositions.push(parseFloat(vals[0]));
                vertexPositions.push(parseFloat(vals[1]));
                vertexPositions.push(parseFloat(vals[2]));

                // And then the texture coords
                vertexTextureCoords.push(parseFloat(vals[3]));
                vertexTextureCoords.push(parseFloat(vals[4]));

                vertexCount += 1;
            }
        }

        worldVertexPositionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, worldVertexPositionBuffer);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertexPositions), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
        worldVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize = 3;
        worldVertexPositionBuffer.numItems = vertexCount;

        worldVertexTextureCoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, worldVertexTextureCoordBuffer);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertexTextureCoords), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
        worldVertexTextureCoordBuffer.itemSize = 2;
        worldVertexTextureCoordBuffer.numItems = vertexCount;
```

So basically I am simply trying to do this to tell the program which texture I want to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally if you want 2 or more textures on the same model you merge them into a [*texture atlas*](http://http.download.nvidia.com/developer/NVTextureSuite/Atlas_Tools/Texture_Atlas_Whitepaper.pdf). you can see [a live example as the last example on this page](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-textures.html)

Otherwise if you really want to use 2 or more textures (hint: except for special cases most programs don't do this) then you

1. make your textures

   ```
   // for each texture
   var tex1 = gl.createTexture();
   gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex1);
   gl.texImage2D(....);
   ```
2. reference more than 1 texture in your shader

   ```
   uniform sampler2D u_tex1;
   uniform sampler2D u_tex2;
   ```
3. Decide on how to choose 1 or the other texture in your shader.

   ```
   vec4 color1 = texture2D(u_tex1, v_coordsForTex1);
   vec4 color2 = texture2D(u_tex2, v_coordsForTex2);
   vec4 color =  mix(color1, color2, mixAmount);
   ```

   It's up to you to decide how to set `mixAmount`. It could be a `uniform`, a formula, it could come from a `varying` that comes from an attribute so each vertex can choose the texture, etc...
4. At render time

   1. Bind the textures to texture units

      ```
      gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0 + unitForTexture1);
      gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex1);
      gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0 + unitForTexture2);
      gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex2);
      ```
   2. Tell the shader which units you put the textures on

      ```
      gl.uniform1f(locationOfUTex1, unitForTexture1);
      gl.uniform1f(locationOfUTex2, unitForTexture2);
      ```

Note: To clarify, many programs use multiple textures when drawing but usually those textures are a color map, a normal map, maybe a glow map, an environment map, an ambient occlusion texture, etc..  But very few programs use multiple color maps for a single draw. Instead they use a texture atlas.

The one common exception I know of is terrain rendering where sometimes they'll have say dirt, grass, and snow textures and blend between them. It's usually rather uglier though than hand draw transitions with a texture atlas. It was mostly used in the early 2000s when 4meg of vram was common. Now most GPUs have 32x that as a minimum.